# Как выбрать рандомный список из файла со списками?

Tags: python, list, случайные-числа

есть два файла

first.py

```
list1=[]
list7=['Какой то','большой', 'список']
list99=[]
```

second.py

```
import random
import first
a = (программа для рандомного списка)
print(a)
```

ещё пару слов,
я знаю кол-во списков,
и их имена типо list + номер строки

Comment: Генерируйте случайный индекс и берите список с этим индексом из всех списков

Comment: ,,можно пример?

Comment: Пример генерации случайного числа?

Comment: Генерируйте случайный индекс и берите список с этим индексом из всех списков.

Comment: Генерация случайного числа не раз освещалась тут, ну а выбрать из списка с помощью `list_of_lists[random_index]`

Answer (score 1):

Напишите так:

```
a = random.choice([list1, list7, list99])
```

Answer (score 1):

Открыть файл, считать строчки в список, выдать случайный элемент из списка:

```
with open("first.py") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(random.choice(lines))
```

Если файл `first.py` больше нигде не используетя, то `import first` можно удалить.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

**first.py**

```
class MyList:
    list1 = ['пусто']
    list7 = ['Какой то','большой', 'список']
    list99 = [1, 2]
    list12 = ['12']
    list77 = ['Какой то22', 'большой22', 'список22']
    list9 = [9, 7]
```

**second.py**

```
import random
from first import MyList

myList = MyList()

_list = []
for i in range(1, 100):
    l = f'list{i}'
    obj = getattr(myList, l, None)
    if obj is not None:
        _list.append(obj)

a = random.choice(_list)        
print(a)
```

Comment: Разве эти списки в классе у ТС?

Comment: @dIm0n как вариант, чтобы выполнить задуманное, я и предложил вставить списки в класс.

Answer (score -1):

second.py

```
from random import randint

import first


index = randint(1,количество списков в файле first.py) 
name = "list" + str(index)
code = "print(first." + name + ")"
eval(code)

#code = "first." + name
#l = eval(code)
```

Comment: Минус за совершенно ненужное применение  eval()

Comment: @Эникейщик почему? Она попросила вывести список из файла first.py. Как по другому объект из другого файла импортировать?

Comment: Отформатируйте код и объясните, где какой файл, если у вас несколько файлов тут

Comment: Как через это присвоть code к чему то(именно то что в list + n, а не print(list+n))

Comment: @КаринаОлдова убрать print со скобками и присвоить результат функции eval переменной (закомментировал строки в ответе)

Comment: @Alexander, eval действительно нужен только для очень узкого класса задач (например, какой-нибудь "калькулятор", где должны интерпретироваться арифметические выражения), в остальных случаях лучше eval не использовать. Есть куча статей, где описано, почему его лучше не использовать. См. например https://habr.com/ru/post/221937/

Comment: Это код еще и не рабочий. Никто не гарантирует, что списки нумерованы по порядку.

Comment: Всё по порядку нумированно по количеству строк в файле, спасибо огромное